# What should I do to have both the synchronous and asynchronous serial communications?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart

You know that ATmega32 supports Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter.

with pins :   RXD & TXD

But it doesn't support Universal synchronous Receiver/Transmitter.

with pins : RXD/TXD & CLOCK

**What should I do to be able to use both the USRT and UART interfaces on my microcontroller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATMega32 has one USART that works either in synchronous (RXD,TXD,XCK) or asynchronous (RXD,TXD) mode, but not both.

If you need second synchronous port, use SPI.